# popup in Chrome browser action only if click on down arrow on right side of the icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension with browser action. I want to make some action on clicking on browser action icon (it is easy, not a problem), and show popup if user clicks on down arrow at the right side of the icon (that is a problem). So, we will receive a functionality similar to the firefox toolbarbutton from XUL. Is it possible to do such thing with Google Chrome?

Just want to make button, like that:
[button](http://s8.postimage.org/xu4ug8uf5/button_example.jpg)

If it is pressed on the main part - it will do something, if on the right "drop-down" part - it will show quick settings page.

But I see only single button possibility.

Comment: Your link is a 403 Forbidden to Google.  I do not think that was what you were intending.

Comment: fixed. Reposted it to other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire `browserAction` button works as a single button. There is no way to detect if a specific area was clicked. The best you can do is either have multiple extensions each having their own button for different actions or have options in the popup that the user selects with a second click.

Comment: It is not a quite question of detecting regions on a button... I modified original question to determine problem a little exactly. But it seems impossible to do such things :(

Comment: Nope. Can't do it. I would suggest creating a second optional extension that would do the popup/dropdown with a second button.